# ios facebook like reactions in objective c

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, emoji

I have a requirement to implement Facebook like reactions in my Xcode project.When the user long press the like button,a list of reactions should come up ,and  then pick up a reaction.Please suggest a better way to implement.

Comment: Use `reactions` [library](https://github.com/yannickl/Reactions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this reaction [library](https://github.com/Eke/EMEmojiableBtn), which explains beautifully how its working.